# Alternative ways to show impact of interaction term

Tags: r, regression

This is a question about communication of results. Mainly I would like to know of alternative ways to communicate the effect of an interaction term of two continuous variable.

I have the following results

```
my_scale <- function(...) as.numeric(scale(...))

iris_scaled <- iris %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-Species), my_scale)

ex <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ (Sepal.Width + Petal.Length)^2, data = iris_scaled)

GGally::ggcoef(ex, conf.level = 0.90, exclude_intercept = TRUE) + 
  ggtitle("Interaction of sepal width and petal length associated with 
smaller sepal length") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

In the above image I can see an association between the interaction term and the outcome, but when speaking to a skeptical audience --- or to prove the relationship to myself --- I have wondered if there are alternative ways to show that an interaction term does exist.

I could, for example, imagine a situation where someone questions the interaction with the following

```
iris_scaled %>% 
  mutate(interaction = Sepal.Width * Petal.Length) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = interaction)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, color = "black") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

How do you talk about interactions in a way that is easily digestible?

#### Edit -some extra stats

I don't want to make it sound like I think that the model with the interaction is better than the one without interaction.

See stats below.

I just wanted to discuss alternative ways to visualize interactions. Maybe the `iris` dataset was a bad choice, but it was the first that came to mind since it had two continuous variables.

```
> broom::glance(ex)
  r.squared adj.r.squared     sigma statistic      p.value df    logLik     AIC      BIC deviance df.residual
 0.8436057     0.8403921 0.3995096  262.5125 1.343031e-58  4 -73.18601 156.372 171.4252 23.30276         146

> ex_noint <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data = iris_scaled)
> broom::glance(ex_noint)
  r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma statistic      p.value df    logLik      AIC      BIC deviance df.residual
 0.8401778     0.8380034 0.402488  386.3862 2.933054e-59  3 -74.81209 157.6242 169.6667  23.8135         147

> anova(ex, ex_noint)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: Sepal.Length ~ (Sepal.Width + Petal.Length)^2
Model 2: Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq   F  Pr(>F)  
1    146 23.303                           
2    147 23.814 -1  -0.51075 3.2 0.07571 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: To be honest, the second plot makes me believe *less* in a meaningful interaction — the regression seems to be driven mainly by a handful of outliers on either side.

Comment: why dont you try decision tree

Comment: @AyushNigam Sure, if you have a visual and explanation then I would like to see it.

Comment: Model selection, tuning, and visualization questions really belong on stats.stackexchange.com, not Stack Overflow, unless there is a specific programming question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is by quantizing one of the continuous variables into example bins to show how the slope of the first variable changes over that range.

```
library(broom)


  augment(
    lm(Sepal.Length ~ (Sepal.Width + Petal.Length)^2, data = iris),
    newdata = 
      expand.grid(Sepal.Width  = range(iris$Sepal.Width),
                  Petal.Length = quantile(iris$Petal.Length))
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width, .fitted, color = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point(data = iris, aes(y = Sepal.Length)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "green") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

You have to be very careful in your accompanying text and labels to point out that these are conditional model predictions. You also have to decide which is the "main" variable and which is the one you're conditioning on. See how it can be turned around:

[image]

Comment: This is very clever. Let me make sure I am interpreting your first plot correctly. Given fitted values vs sepal width, as petal length increases the slope decreases. This is consistent with the negative interaction term from multiple regression.